# Is there a better way to turn HTML to plain text in JavaScript than a series of Regex search/replaces

Tags: javascript, regex, text

My goal is to retrieve HTML via a REST API and convert it to plain text. Then I send it through another API to Slack, which does not accept HTML (so far as I'm aware).

I am using a series of Regex scripts to accomplish this.

```
var noHtml = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
var noHtmlEncodeSpace = noHtml.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
var noHtmlEncodersquo = noHtmlEncodeSpace.replace(/&rsquo;/g, "'");
var noHtmlEncodeldsquo = noHtmlEncodersquo.replace(/&lsquo;/g, "'");
var noHtmlEncodeSingleQuote = noHtmlEncodeldsquo.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
var noHtmlEncodeldquo = noHtmlEncodeSingleQuote.replace(/&ldquo;/g, "`");
var noHtmlEncodeDoubleQuote = noHtmlEncodeldquo.replace(/&quot;/g, "`");
var noHtmlEncoderdquo = noHtmlEncodeDoubleQuote.replace(/&rdquo;/g, "`");
```

The results are as expected. But transforming HTML to plain text seems like it is a common-enough task in JavaScript that there may be a smarter way to do it.

I am new to JavaScript. Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `DOMParser` to safely parse the HTML string into a document, after which you can retrieve the `textContent` of the document:

```js
const htmlStr = `<div>
foo &nbsp;&nbsp;  &rsquo;&rsquo;
</div>
<script>
alert('evil');
</` + `script>
<img src="badsrc" onerror="alert('evil')">`;


const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.body.textContent);
```

Depending on the text spacing desired, you might use the `innerText` property instead:

```
doc.body.innerText
```

(This is in contrast to, for example, setting the `innerHTML` of a newly created element, which wouldn't be as safe - the "evil" scripts could be executed before the `textContent` is retrieved)